# Android ViewFlipper change background with image from URL how to

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm trying to change a background image on my ViewFlipper... But can't get it to work... Do I have to download the image before set it to the ViewFlipper? .. I saw an example where the URL is used.. But I can't! .

this.vf.setBackgroundDrawable("http://path_to_background_image");

Comment: yes, you have to download it.

Comment: Do you have an example? .. I have tried a few, but can't get it to work..

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself...

```
Bitmap bg_img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new 
URL(webservice.getString("background_image_url")).getContent());
                    vf.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg_img));
```